# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 - in libboost_thread-mt.a

Tags: x86-64, boost-thread

```
 boost::atomics::detail::lockpool::get_lock_for(void const volatile*)", referenced from:
 boost::thread_detail::enter_once_region(boost::once_flag&)   in libboost_thread-mt.a(once.o)
 boost::thread_detail::commit_once_region(boost::once_flag&)   in libboost_thread-mt.a(once.o)
 boost::thread_detail::rollback_once_region(boost::once_flag&)   in libboost_thread-mt.a(once.o)
 ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

I am running OS X Version 10.9.

Installed boost using the following option:

sudo port install boost +universal

```
$ ar -tv libboost_thread-mt.a
rw-r--r--     502/501       21776 Dec  1 22:44 2013 __.SYMDEF
rw-r--r--     502/80       925520 Dec  1 22:44 2013 thread.o
rw-r--r--     502/80        18248 Dec  1 22:44 2013 once.o
rw-r--r--     502/80        51216 Dec  1 22:44 2013 future.o

$ nm -a once.o 
0000000000003168 s EH_frame0
0000000000003080 s GCC_except_table0
00000000000030cc s GCC_except_table1
0000000000003118 s GCC_except_table2
             U __Unwind_Resume
0000000000000000 T __ZN5boost13thread_detail17enter_once_regionERNS_9once_flagE
0000000000003188 S __ZN5boost13thread_detail17enter_once_regionERNS_9once_flagE.eh
0000000000000130 T __ZN5boost13thread_detail18commit_once_regionERNS_9once_flagE
00000000000031c0 S __ZN5boost13thread_detail18commit_once_regionERNS_9once_flagE.eh
00000000000001a0 T __ZN5boost13thread_detail20rollback_once_regionERNS_9once_flagE
00000000000031f0 S __ZN5boost13thread_detail20rollback_once_regionERNS_9once_flagE.eh
0000000000003010 d __ZN5boost13thread_detailL10once_mutexE
0000000000003050 d __ZN5boost13thread_detailL7once_cvE
             U __ZN5boost7atomics6detail8lockpool12get_lock_forEPVKv
             U __ZSt9terminatev
             U ___gxx_personality_v0
             U _pthread_cond_broadcast
             U _pthread_cond_wait
             U _pthread_mutex_lock
             U _pthread_mutex_unlock
```

One can notice the line "U __ZN5boost7atomics6detail8lockpool12get_lock_forEPVKv"

indicating get_lock_for is not defined. This is causing the issue.

How to get rid of this error. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Link with more libraries. :)

`-lboost_atomic` for the `get_lock_for` in particular.

Comment: You are living in the past, my friend: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/atomic.html

Comment: My apologies, thought it was header-only :$